# get the size in bytes of a StringIO object

Tags: python-2.7, stringio, cstringio

Is it possible to get the size in bytes of a *StringIO* object?  or should i write it to disk every time i want to get its size?
I have searched a lot but without success.  There *.**sizeof**()* but i don't think that is what i want.

I am iterating over a list of filenames

```
temp=StringIO()
for idx,filename in enumerate(filenames):
    temp.write('something')
    if ((temp.__sizeof__()+os.path.getsize(os.path.join(inputf,filenames[idx])))/1048576.0 >= 128.0):
        (do something)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should seek to the end and use `tell()`:

```
temp.write('something')
temp.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
if ((temp.tell()+...
```

Example:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import os
temp = StringIO()
temp.write("abc€")
temp.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
print temp.tell() #6
```

Comment: i think  _.tell()_ would give me the number of elements in temp. I would have the size of temp in byte, like when you are using _os.path.getsize(file)_

Comment: I would accept your answer as it answer my question, but with seek() would it rewind temp from the beginning, as i am concatenating XML files and i would write the my temp file to disk only if it have a certain size.    I fear that with seek, it will reset my temp each time and i will never get to pass the if statement.

Comment: It depends how you construct your loop